# Difference between div~div and div:not(:first-of-type)?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is there a difference between `div~div` and `div:not(:first-of-type)`? Aside from IE6 whatever errors, are there cases where they would do different things?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In terms of matching elements, there is no difference. Any `div` that follows some other `div` within the same parent is, by necessity, not the first element of type `div` within its parent.

If the sibling selector were `+` and not `~`, then `div+div` has the added condition that the following element must appear immediately after the preceding element. This is not the case with `~` — any number of siblings of any other kind may appear between the two.

If the pseudo-class were `:first-child` and not `:first-of-type`, then `div:not(:first-child)` will still match `div:first-of-type` if the first `div` within its parent is not its first child.

Here's an illustration:

```
<section>
    <div></div> <!-- div:first-child or div:first-of-type -->
    <div></div> <!-- div+div or div~div or div:nth-of-type(2) -->
    <p></p>
    <div></div> <!-- div+p+div or div~div or div:nth-of-type(3),
                     but not div+div -->
</section>
<section>
    <h1></h1>   <!-- h1:first-child -->
    <div></div> <!-- div:first-of-type or div:nth-child(2) -->
    <div></div> <!-- div~div or div:nth-of-type(2) or div:nth-child(3) -->
</section>
```

In terms of [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity), there is a difference. If you have CSS rules with both selectors matching the same elements, then `div:not(:first-of-type)` will take precedence due to the `:first-of-type` pseudo-class. Notice that the `:not()` itself is not counted — only its argument is considered.

Here's another illustration:

```css
div {
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

/* 1 pseudo-class, 1 type -> specificity = 0-1-1 */
div:not(:first-of-type) {
    border-color: green;
}

/* 2 types                -> specificity = 0-0-2 */
div ~ div {
    border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</section>
```

Comment: There may be a difference in [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity). From my tests, `li:not(:first-of-type)` will override `li~li`.

Comment: @Sergey K: You are right. I hadn't thought about specificity. I'll edit my answer.